# Spark Application: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have setup a spark cluster using two VMs with high RAM available on Ambari. Also, I have executed the same job in other clusters(HDInsights) and it was optimized the executor, driver memory, vcore settings.

However, when I run the job in this new cluster of VMs, I am getting the

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to
>   create new native thread

I have changed the ulimit -u and ulimit -n parameters and tried executing the jobs. It did not help. Please let me know if anyone has an more ideas in tackling these error.

Answer (score 0):

Typically that's an issue with your JVM memory which you would normally set with the -Xmx property. It looks like that's disallowed in Spark and you will need to specify your heap sizes with [spark.executor.memory](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)